# Adding Impulse Noise in Image manually

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

How can salt & pepper noise be added to an image separately depending on the PROBABILITY of salt and pepper. `imnoise` would take ONE value for the noise density as a whole and that value is the measure for both salt (white dots) and pepper (black dots). I want to know if we have just to add white (salt) and then black (pepper) noise separately with two different probabilities. What equation would have to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clc;
close all;
originalImage = imread('Cameraman.tif');
[rows cols] = size(originalImage);
totalPixels = int32(rows * cols);
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(originalImage);
percentage = str2double(cell2mat(inputdlg('Enter the percent noise: ', 'Enter answer', 1, {'2'}))) / 100.;
numberOfNoisePixels = int32(percentage * double(rows) * double(cols));
locations = randi(totalPixels, [numberOfNoisePixels, 1]);
noisyImage = originalImage;
noisyImage(locations) = 255;
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(noisyImage, []);
```

Source

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/YcF2xZwnq1o

That does Salt Noise, Pepper noise would be

```
noisyImage(locations) = 0;
```

instead of

```
noisyImage(locations) = 255;
```

Comment: just one question before i hit the correct ;). the percentage of noise and the 'probability' of noise. are these two same terms in image processing?

Comment: Not exactly, But close enough. The % is a fixed term, so a 0.05 in % would mean there are ALWAYS 0.05 * Total pixels. Probability would be there are close to 0.05 * total pixels. as Pixels increase the two terms would start to mean the same thing

Comment: This approach doesn't prevent salt and noise to be added at the same pixels (which might be desired or not)

Answer (score 3):

```
img = .5*ones(100,200); %// example image
p_salt = .05; %// probability of salt
p_pepper = .01; %// probability of pepper

if strcmp(class(img),'uint8')
    salt_value = uint8(255);
else
    salt_value = 1;
end
pepper_value = 0;

aux = rand(size(img)); %// generate random values
img(aux<=p_salt) = salt_value;  %// add salt
img((aux>p_salt) & (aux<=p_salt+p_pepper)) = pepper_value; %// add pepper

imshow(img) %// show image
```

This approach is similar to that used in `imnoise`, and avoids salt and pepper to be added at the same pixels. It assumes `p_salt + p_pepper` is at most 1.

[image]

Comment: would there be any effect on this code depending on intensity values being between 0-255 or 0-1?

Answer (score 0):

This code is simple and useful(Same imnoise in MATLAB)

```
im=imread('Parrot.jpg');
B=rgb2gray(im);
%if Pa==Pb;
percen=10;
%Noise level 10
Prob_den_f=255*percen/100;
NoiseImg = B;
Rmatrix = randint(size(B,1),size(B,2),[0,255]);
NoiseImg(Rmatrix <=Prob_den_f/2) = 0;
NoiseImg(Rmatrix >Prob_den_f/2&Rmatrix<Prob_den_f) =255;
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(NoiseImg),title('Add ''Salt and Pepper'' Noise'); 
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(B),title('Original Image');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation instead of just posting code.